# How to properly resize select form input

Tags: html, forms, html-select

I have a form which uses both text fields as well as `select` options. I styled the form using the following CSS:

```
input[type=text] {
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    text-indent: 10px;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.14);
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

select {
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.14);
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
}
```

The problem is that for some reason, the `select` options are not properly using the `width` and `height`. The actual select box is rather small is comparison to the text fields. They end up like:

[image]

How can I properly resize a `select` option using CSS to make it have the same size as text fields? I tried using the `width` and `height` as shown above, but this does not give me the desired effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
select {
    min-width:265px;
    min-height: 45px;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.14);
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
}
```

Comment: Well that worked! Never knew `min` would actually be a plus ;) Well done.